# Dynamically set up onmouseup with an object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am setting up an `onmouseup` event like this:

```
html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event, \'' + tileInfo.targetURL + '\', \'' + tileInfo.id + '\')"
```

where `func` is a var with a value like "launchA" or "launchB".  The launchA and launchB methods expect three arguments, event, targetURL (which is a string) and id (which is also a string).

Since both `targetUR`L and id are properties of the same object (`tileInfo`), I would prefer to pass `tileInfo` to the launch methods, and let them make references to `tileInfo.targetURL` and `tileInfo.id`, but when I set it up like this:

```
html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event, \'' + tileInfo + '\')"
```

when it hits launchA, `tileInfo` is an Object, but `tileInfo.id` is undefined.

Comment: Your using JavaScript to output HTML that needs to execute JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know what your scope is on tileInfo.. but you could maybe.. `html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event, tileInfo)'"...`

Comment: tileInfo is a parameter to the function where this code is.  Coded like this, it is undefined at the event handler.  This would work if it were a global variable, but I am setting up these mouseup events for a number of controls, so I can't have this as a global variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript attach new property to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026891/javascript-attach-new-property-to-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifics were provided in a separate but related question, which was answered here:  [Javascript attach new property to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026891/javascript-attach-new-property-to-element/18066082#18066082).