# Javascript attach new property to element

Tags: javascript

I have an object, X, and some code that creates a div and assigns id = X.ID.  After the html is created, I assign the object to the div, like this:

```
document.getElementById(X.ID).XValue = X;
```

If I set a break after that statement, I can evaulate `document.getElementById(X.ID).XValue` and see all the properties of X.

While I was creating the html, I added `onmouseup="MOUSE_UP(event)".`

```
var aProp = {};
aProp.ThisValue = "This";
aProp.ThatValue = "That";
aProp.Id = 5;
var html = '<div id="' + aProp.Id + '"';
var func = 'MOUSE_UP';
html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event) ">';
html += '</div>';
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += html;
document.getElementById(aProp.Id).XVALUE = aProp;

function MOUSE_UP(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.XValue.ThisValue);
}
```

Now, when I set a break at MOUSE_UP, event.currentTarget is my div (`event.currentTarget.id == X.ID`), but event.currentTarget.XValue is undefined.

Why is XValue undefined here when it was defined earlier?

Comment: Did you mean `onmouseup="MOUSE_UP(event)"`? The extra single quote could be throwing things off...

Comment: You might find this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Is this roughly what you're doing? Because it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/jeffman/6whJ3/

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I am doing.  I tried         var aProp = { };
        aProp.ThisValue = "This";
        aProp.ThatValue = "That";
        aProp.Id = 5;
        var html = '<div id="' + aProp.Id + '"';
        var func = 'myMouseUp';
        html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event) ">';
        html += '</div>';

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += html;
        document.getElementById( aProp.Id ).NewProp = aProp;
        
function myMouseUp( event ) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.NewProp.ThisValue);
}  but I didn't get this to work in your tool).

Comment: @KellyCline Even the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/EL2sd/2/) you posted in a comment works. The error has to be somewhere else outside of the code you've provided. Unless... In the fiddle I've only added some text into `#5` to get it clickable.

Comment: @Teemu - I am new to jsFiddle so this may not work, but I have reworked the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/EL2sd/16/.  I had over-simplified the problem description:  I am actually creating a series of these divs on the fly.  What I can demonstrate is that the assignment of NewProp to an element is good until the loop takes us to another; in other words, only the last assignment sticks.  However many divs I create in onload, only the last one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like setting `innerHTML` of `#test` would wipe out all *custom properties* from its children. You can check this in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBffm/). When you'll run the fiddle as it is, you'll notice `NewProp` of `#1` will become `undefined` after adding more content with `test.innerHTML += ...`  If you log `tabIndex` instead of `NewProp`, you'll get the correct values.

This happens because `+=` operator is just a shortcut for a statement like `a = a + b`, which can also be written `a += b`.

Basicly you create a string from the inner HTML of `#test`, then add another string to it, and finally replace the original `innerHTML` of `#test` with this new string. All previous elements in `#test` are replaced with new ones, which don't have the custom properties set.

When setting `id` property for an element, also `id` attribute is added to the HTML, hence they are a part of `innerHTML` of `#test`, and are added to the newly created HTML too.

If you use proper DOM manipulation instead of setting `innerHTML`, you'll get the results you want. The code below uses [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) methods instead of setting `innerHTML`.

```
function myMouseUp(e) {
    alert("at MouseUp " + e.currentTarget.NewProp.ThisValue);
}

function buildOneDiv(aProp) {
    var html = document.createElement('div');
    aProp.ThisValue = 'This is ' + aProp.id;
    aProp.ThatValue = 'That is ' + aProp.id;
    html.id = aProp.id;
    html.addEventListener('mouseup', myMouseUp, false);
    html.innerHTML = 'Test ' + aProp.id;
    return html;
}

function buildDivs(x) {
    var html = buildOneDiv(x);
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(html);
    document.getElementById(x.id).NewProp = x;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var aProp, i;
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        aProp = {};
        aProp.id = i;
        buildDivs(aProp);
    }
};
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCZhH/).

Comment: @KellyCline Setting `innerHTML` really clears custom properties from elements, you can check it with this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSWPG/1/). If you comment out the line which adds the 4th paragraph, you can see a custom property of each `p`. Your workaround works, because it uses a global object `myDivs` instead of custom properties of elements.

Comment: @KellyCline Any comments?

Comment: Plus one for defining what the problem really is and demonstrating that createElement/appendChild solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as it is a clarification and a work-around.

Given this html

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

and this code

```
function myMouseUp(e) {
    alert("at MouseUp " + e.currentTarget.NewProp.ThisValue);
}

function buildOneDiv(aProp) {
    aProp.ThisValue = "This";
    aProp.ThatValue = "That";
    var html = '<div id="' + aProp.id + '"';
    var func = 'myMouseUp';
    html += ' onmouseup="' + func + '(event) ">';
    html += 'Test ' + aProp.id + '</div>';
    return html;
}

function buildDivs(x) {
    var html = buildOneDiv(x);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += html;
    document.getElementById( x.id ).NewProp = x;
}

window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var aProp = {};
        aProp.id = i;
        buildDivs(aProp);
    }
};
```

The end result is that only the LAST div whose onmouseup is defined will have a legitimate value for NewProp at myMouseUp.  For each other div, this property is undefined.  This is why I got some comments indicating that "It does work."  It works for ONE, which is all I had in my example.  (This is the clarification.)

My workaround is to add a global object to be an associative array and change two statements:

```
var myDivs = {};    // global
```

Replace

`document.getElementById( x.id ).NewProp = x;`

in buildDivs with

`myDivs[x.id] = x;`

and replace

`alert("at MouseUp " + e.currentTarget.NewProp.ThisValue);`

in myMouseUp with

`alert(myDivs[e.currentTarget.id].ThisValue );`.

I'd still like to know why the original approach doesn't work.